# Создание обязательной с обеих сторон связи в mySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Создаю внешний ключ, строю диаграмму при помощи Reverse Engineer в mySQL workbench, на диаграмме связь обозначается как необязательная. Как создать обязательную связь?

Таблица-предок:

```
CREATE TABLE `discipline` (
`short_disc_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`full_name` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`short_disc_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Таблица с внешним ключом:

```
CREATE TABLE `teacher` (
`full_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`post` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`qualification` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`autohrity` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`discipline` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`full_name`),
KEY `discipline` (`discipline`),
CONSTRAINT `teacher_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`discipline`) 
REFERENCES     `discipline` (`short_disc_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Вот какая получается связь:
[image: Вот как получается связь:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Можно долго бегать за следствиями неверного предположения, хе-хе.*

У вас всё правильно: есть внешний ключ и ограничение на не-`NULL`. Отсутствие связи исключено.

Ах да, пунктир. **Пунктир не про необязательность.** Он указывает на то, что связь **не идентифицирующая**. И здесь это именно так: внешний ключ этой связи не является частью первичного ключа таблицы.

В данном случае связь была бы **идентифицирующей**, если бы первичный ключ `teachers` содержал `discipline`. Не уверен, что это хорошая идея для вашего случая, потому что для формально точной идентификации учителя в базе потребуется не только его имя, но и дисциплина. Немного странно. У вас учитель может преподавать несколько дисциплин? Хм... Решайте.

Можете это проверить, нарисовав такую связь в редакторе и посмотрев на изменения.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо:) Такой вопрос: внешний ключ можно включить в состав первичного ключа? Это не для этого случая вопрос.

Comment: @xd720p м... Если под "внешним ключом" понимается столбец (а не constraint на нём), то да, конечно.

Comment: например, есть таблица Посещение(_№ зачётки, дата_, присутствие). Атрибут № зачётки получается из связи с таблицей Студент(_№ зачётки_, ФИО и т.д.), где он является первичным ключом. Можно ли в таблице Посещение сделать вот такой составной ключ [№ зачётки, дата]? Ведь только по такому ключу можно однозначно определить посещение.

Comment: @xd720p если первичный ключ студента это номер его зачётки, то да, это неплохой пример идентифицирующей связи.